# Update query not working in C#

Tags: c#

```
protected void btn_redeem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int lol = int.Parse(lbl_TotalPrice.Text,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency);
    double nprice = lol * 0.05;
    int newpoints=0 ;
    if (int.Parse(Session["points"].ToString()) >= 1000)
    {
        double redeem = lol - nprice;
        lbl_TotalPrice.Text = redeem.ToString("C");
         newpoints = int.Parse(Session["points"].ToString()) - 1000;
    }
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HealthDBContext"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string queryStr = "UPDATE Users SET Points ='" + newpoints + "'WHERE UserName=" + Session["New"].ToString();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: You could at least give some indication of what's not working. What error  / exception is occurring? Where in the code?

Comment: No exception message ? We cannot read your mind...

Comment: Its not updating the user's points

Comment: I am sorry, i dont understand what you mean. I have just started learning.

Comment: A command should be executed to do anything to your database. Your code has no _com.ExecuteNonQuery();_ call thus no update happens. Said that learn how to use a parameterized query and do not build sql text concatenating strings taken from the user input. It is very dangerous and source of innumerable bugs.

Comment: You must call "com.ExecuteNonQuery();" before closing the connection, to execute the query.

Comment: Ah! Thanks Steve! Really appreciate it! I'll keep that in mind from now on. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add .ExecuteNonQuery to execute the query, and add try-catch-block to catch any exception:

```
try
{
    ...
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```